# how to write unit tests for directive with events

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a directive as below.

```
maApp.directive('pwCheck', [function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            var firstPassword = '#' + attrs.pwCheck;
            elem.add(firstPassword).on('keyup', function() {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('passwordMatch', elem.val() === $(firstPassword).val());
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

I'm trying to write unit test for this and I'm unable to get the keyup event fired successfully. I an able to set the text to the NewPassword field and verify it with scope. But, the part I'm missing is how to set the form to be invalid when both the NewPassword and ConfirmPassword fields have different values.

```
describe('Directives', function() {
    beforeEach(module('maApp'));

    describe('pw-check directive', function() {
        var element, scope, emailForm, html = '<form name="emailForm"><input name="NewPassword" id="NewPassword" ng-model="NewPassword" /><input name="ConfirmPassword" ng-model="ConfirmPassword" pw-check="NewPassword" /><div ng-show="emailForm.$error"><span class="text-danger" ng-show="emailForm.$error.passwordMatch">Passwords don\'t match.</span></div></form>';

        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
            scope = $rootScope;
            element = angular.element(html);
            $compile(element)(scope);
            scope.$digest();
            emailForm = scope.emailForm;
        }));

        it('should show the text from the album template', function () {
            expect(emailForm.$valid).toBe(true);
            emailForm.NewPassword.$setViewValue('a');
            expect(scope.NewPassword).toBe('a');

            var event = angular.element.Event('keyup');
            event.which = 65;
            var newPwdInput = $('#NewPassword');
            $(newPwdInput).trigger(event);
            expect(emailForm.$valid).toBe(false);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you try element.find('#newPassword').trigger('keyup', { which: 65 }); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you find difficult to test your directive because you shouldn't be binding events by id using jquery when you don't really need to. The right approach to your directive would be using [parsers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#properties_%24parsers):

```
maApp.directive('pwCheck', [function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            var firstPassword = attrs.pwCheck;
            scope.$watch(attrs.pwCheck, function(newValue, oldValue) {
              ctrl.$setValidity('passwordMatch', ctrl.$modelValue === newValue);
            });

            function passwordCheckerParser(passwordEntered) {
                ctrl.$setValidity('passwordMatch', passwordEntered === scope.$eval(attrs.pwCheck));
                return passwordEntered;
            }
            ctrl.$parsers.push(passwordCheckerParser);
        }
    };
}]);
```

If you want to trigger a 'keyup' event you just need to do element.trigger('keyup'). Although with the way I've written your directive you don't need to do that and actually this should just work:

```
describe('Directives', function() {
    beforeEach(module('maApp'));

    describe('pw-check directive', function() {
        var element, scope, emailForm, html = '<form name="emailForm"><input name="NewPassword" id="NewPassword" ng-model="NewPassword" /><input name="ConfirmPassword" ng-model="ConfirmPassword" pw-check="NewPassword" /><div ng-show="emailForm.$error"><span class="text-danger" ng-show="emailForm.$error.passwordMatch">Passwords don\'t match.</span></div></form>';

        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
            scope = $rootScope;
            element = angular.element(html);
            $compile(element)(scope);
            scope.$digest();
            emailForm = scope.emailForm;
        }));

        it('should show the text from the album template', function () {
            expect(emailForm.$valid).toBe(true);
            emailForm.NewPassword.$setViewValue('a');
            expect(scope.NewPassword).toBe('a');

            expect(emailForm.$valid).toBe(false);
        });
    });
});
```

Let me know if you have any questions or something doesn't work the way you expected it to work.

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xIQa0t?p=preview)

Comment: the directive you suggested works (except that the line should be "var firstPassword = '#' + attrs.pwCheck;" (somehow you missed the '#' + part. Thanks for that, but the unit tests is not working with $.valid. I had to change it to expect($(emailForm).hasClass("ng-invalid-password-mismatch")); Any idea why I can't check $valid?

Comment: Why do you need a '#'? I thought you used that to do a jQuery selector by id. What version of angular are you using? Also how does emailForm look like after you setViewValue?

Comment: I'm using 1.2.2 and it is part of a larger project, so I can't upgrade. And not sure what your next question means.

Comment: Try doing $scope.digest(); after setviewValue to see if it updates $valid but you shouldn't need to.

Comment: There's another issue with the way your code is doing and I can repro this in the plunkr you've provided. Add some text, say 'asdf' in the first field. Tab to the next field. Type, say 'bc' in the second field. You'll see the 'passwords do not match' text appear.  Clear contents of second field and then clear contents of the first field, you'll still see 'passwords do not match' text.

Comment: I've edited the plnkr. Let me know if that works better for you.

Comment: Spoke too soon. The code worked, but I still don't have code coverage for the 'keyup' trigger.

Comment: You don't need to test 'keyup' since you are using a parser, angularJS own test will make sure that the parsers are called on input events.

Comment: Are you saying the keyup and parser are mutually exclusive? Your plunkr will not work as expected if I removed the keyup call.

Comment: Yes, a parser gets called every time the input changes ($setViewValue is called), so you don't need to trigger a keyup in your test. What part doesn't work as expected?

Comment: I've just realised I left the 'keyup' event handler on the plnkr when I shouldn't have. I've updated the plnkr to reflect that. (Also I corrected that I wrote modelValue instead of $modelValue). Everything should be working now.

Comment: Hail @Wawy Hail! Thanks for helping me through this.